# How to signup for Azure subscription for Transliteration?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am able to Translator service subscription on Azure. However, I am not able  to use transliteration api. I do see the documentation on how to use the api here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-transliterate.

The keys I am using are same as the translator keys:
[image: Translator Keys and endpoint]

I am using the key1 from the diagram in the header: Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key and the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region as southcentralus.

However, as per the transliteration document I am using the endpoint:
https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/transliterate?api-version=3.0
I always get a response:

```
{401 Unauthorized 401 HTTP/2.0 2 0 map[Access-Control-Expose-Headers:[X-RequestId] Content-Length:[111] Content-Type:[text/plain; charset=utf-8] Date:[Sun, 02 Jul 2023 07:09:12 GMT] Strict-Transport-Security:[max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains] X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff] X-Requestid:[TLIT.MW1P.E838.0702T0709.XXXXXX]] {0x1400034XXXX} 111 [] false false map[] 0x140003XXXXX 0x1400027XXXX}
```

How do I subscribe to get the keys for transliteration?

I tried the Curl. and I am getting the following error:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/transliterate?api-version=3.0&language=ja&fromScript=Jpan&toScript=Latn"  -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 949dbd2ea6154057af889f34939XXXX" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @request.txt
```

{"error":{"code":401000,"message":"The request is not authorized because credentials are missing or invalid."}}
I have made sure the key I am using in "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" is same as what I obtain from the Key1 in the screenshot I showed. Is that the correct key to use?

Comment: Show your full request: Body, header, authentication.

Comment: @VyDo Here is the request I am sending:
&{POST https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com//transliterate?api-version=3.0&language=kn&fromScript=Latn&toScript=Knda HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Type:[application/json] Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:[949dbd2ea6154057af889f34939XXXXX] Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region:[southtcentralus]] {[{"Text":"Hello"}]} 0x104db7900 22 [] false api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com map[] map[] <nil> map[]   <nil> <nil> <nil> 0x1400003e0e0}

Comment: You put your request to your question, format it.

Comment: @VyDo I added the curl command for clarity above.

Comment: ``` 
string subscriptionKey = "Your Speech service subscriptionKey";
            string region = "your Speech service Location/Region";
            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(subscriptionKey, region);
            config.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-US-AriaNeural";
            string inputText = "Hello, here is a sample text that will be said aloud.";
            using (var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config))
            {
                using (var result = await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(inputText)) 
```

Comment: ``` if (result.Reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
                    {
                      using (var audioDataStream = AudioDataStream.FromResult(result))
                        {
                            await audioDataStream.SaveToWaveFileAsync("output.wav");
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine($"After being read out, the text was saved as output. wav");
                    }
                  ```

Comment: ``` else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
                    {
                        var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");
                        if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
                            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails=[{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]");
                        }}```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo with the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region value I am setting. Sigh...